# Does union of parameters in generic type results in union of generic types?

Tags: typescript

Somewhere I read this to be true

```
WhateverType<A | B | C, D> =  WhateverType<A, D> |  WhateverType<B, D> |  WhateverType<C, D>
```

Is this true? Can't find info in the documentation.

Comment: This depends entirely on the definition of `WhateverType`. Some generic types distribute over their parameters, others do not.

Comment: @kaya3 That is why I got confused because it is from a book "Programming Typescript" (page 145). They didn't claim this for `WhateverType` just the way it was written **strongly** suggested it could work for any type. There was example with a specific type though.

Comment: If you quote the part of the book, with proper context, then somebody can probably explain what it is saying. Very likely it means that some example in the book has this property, not that all generic types do. The truth is that many don't.

Comment: @kaya3 Please check here: https://ibb.co/KF6RKTP, Step 2

Comment: *"If it wasn't for the distributive property of conditional types, ..."* - there you go. It's talking about this particular example, which distributes over unions because it's defined using a distributive conditional type.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your question is not true for all generic types. It can be refuted with a simple example containing a function type.

```
type SomeType<T> = (arg: T) => void
```

The generic parameter `T` of the type `SomeType` is used as the parameter of a function here.

Let's look at the types `A` and `B`.

```
type A = SomeType<string | number>
// type A = (arg: string | number) => void

type B = SomeType<string> | SomeType<number>
// type B = (arg: never) => void
```

You can visually see how these types are different. And while `A` is a subtype of `B`, `B` is not a subtype of `A`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygewLZQCqSgHlQPhgXhgAoBDAJwHMAuGVASgLwDcEBLAE2FAxgEED4yNBkwBnEGVYA7CjAA+MKQFckAIyhkcwAPTaY4aHwGlKNcZJnzFK9WQb5mbTt0MAhAYhTpoYidIp4Cp7CPspqGlq6+jzuhCbUilBMGvaOHFwusABKUKJKADYgAu5QAB4gUFLsokYA-PpkSrA0AGYk+aJQOnptHVBAA)